# Random link without repeat - User session

Tags: php, session, random

I have 7 links and I need to display one link per page or page view without repeat the links from previous views.

The links need to be displayed in a random way and all 7 links must be shown to the user if he/she visit 7 pages, (one per page), if the user visit more than 7 pages the cicle will start again.

I hope the question is clear.
Thanks and sorry for my english
Daniel

Answer (score 3):

You should store the previously visited links in the session or database. you can simply shuffle the links, and iterate trough. Then check if it's been visited before - and keep on going until you find one. If you can't find on (done iteration) you can assume all 7 has been visited, and you can reset the session/database.

Small code example (note: pseudocode).

```
$aLinks = array(1, 2, .., ..);
shuffle($aLinks);

$sLinkToShow = null;
foreach($aLinks as $aLink) {
    if (seenBefore()) continue;
    $sLinkToShow = $aLink['link'];
}

if (is_null($sLinktoShow)) { 
    // seen all
}
echo $sLinkToShow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the shuffled links in the session and use them one by one:

```
$links = array('a', 'b', 'c', …);

if (empty($_SESSION['links'])) {
    // first time visit, populate random order in session
    $_SESSION['links'] = array_keys($links);
    shuffle($_SESSION['links']);
}

// pop first link
$link = array_shift($_SESSION['links']);

// cycle array; or don't, to create a different order next time
$_SESSION['links'][] = $link;

// output link
echo $links[$link];
```

Comment: Hi... your example works but the random effect is not the desired one, since some of the values get repeated, Yes they are random, but not all the options in the array are shown before start a new cicle again. I just let "a", "b" and "c" as values on the array but after a few page views the values get repeated. I just check that a few times, not all values are show.

Comment: @Daniel That should not be the case. Try `var_dump($_SESSION['links'])` to see the state of the queue, it should cycle perfectly.

Comment: Yes... you are correct, sorry, i just clean up the browser, and check it again, it works perfect Thanks a lot